# Lectura de valores <NULL> dentro de un archivo de texto

Tags: php

Amigos

Tengo un problema cuando leo un archivo de texto, es especifico los `<NULL>`, los cuales no los detecta fgets cuando voy recorriendo linea por linea,  todos los valores los almaceno en un array para despues pasarlos a una base de datos, solo que quisiera saber como puedo interpretarlos

[image: Archivo de Texto]

De antemano agradezco su atencion

Comment: Creo que le pasa justamente lo que ocurrió en la pregunta, que escribiste `<NULL>`  sin la indicación de que era código y no se veía nada, o sea, puede que `fgets` tenga problemas al encontrar la etiqueta `<`. Una opción sería, si tienes acceso al archivo, hacer un buscar-reemplazar de `<NULL>` por `NULL`, entonces creo que no habrá ningún problema.

Comment: Efectivamente el problema se encontraba en los signos <>; utilizando la funcion str_replace("","NULL",$campos); me soluciono el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente el problema se encontraba en los signos <>; utilizando la funcion str_replace("","NULL",$campos); me soluciono el problema.

Agradezco el apoyo A. Cedano